# Returning rows where there is no reconnect timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, so please forgive me for what seems like a basic question.

I have a database called 'timestamps' that is structured like this;

| ID | Connected_Unixtime | Disconnected_Unixtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1658260585 | 1658260645 |
| 1 | 1658260465 | 1658260525 |
| 2 | 1658260345 | 1658260405 |
| 1 | 1658260225 | 1658260285 |

I'm trying to write some SQL that returns rows of IDs that disconnected and have had more than one hour since the last connect. So if there's an ID that has a Disconnected_Unixtime but no Connected_Unixtime after one hour of disconnecting, return the most recent row.

Basically the results should look like this, with just IDs that didn't have a new connection after an hour:

| ID | Connected_Unixtime | Disconnected_Unixtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1658260585 | 1658260645 |
| 2 | 1658260345 | 1658260405 |

I tried to use the not exist operator since a new row is created every time an ID connects. This is what I came up with, but it's not correct.

```
select *
from timestamps
where not exists (select *
                  from timestamps
                  where (Disconnected_Unixtime) > now() - interval 1 hour
                  order by Disconnected_Unixtime desc
                 )
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: should in the end result not at least be one ID 1? and which mysql version are you using

Comment: Hi @nbk yes you are right, it should have ID 1. And I'm using version 5.7.37-google-log

Comment: tabes with unique key and your old version prevent from formulating a good answer but search for Lag and mysql 5.7